# Truthmaker Maximalism

Tags: metaphysics

What does it mean for a theory to have brute, unexplained necessary connections? Like for example, Truthmaker Maximalism is mentioned to have brute, unexplained necessary connections due to the way the theory tries to address negative existentials (since the absence of a truthmaker for proposition p is a truthmaker for proposition ~p). What does this mean and why is this an issue with Ockham’s razor?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it means that truthmaker maximalism requires that a lot of things exist - one for every true proposition - but it's hard to justify the actual existence of these things.  Occam's razor says (in one crude interpretation) to reduce the number of entities in an explanation, and if you have a truthmaker for everything, that's a lot of extra entities you didn't necessarily need.

A deeper interpretation of Occam's razor says to choose the simplest explanation that agrees with the facts, even though this explanation may have a large number of entities.  For example, the laws of physics are a fairly simple explanation for a great variety of complex phenomena, even though they propose the existence of subatomic particles in very large numbers.